# Sleep in Future::poll

Tags: rust, async-await, sleep, rust-tokio, crossterm

I am trying to create a future polling for inputs from the `crossterm` crate, which does not provide an asynchronous API, as far as I know.

At first I tried to do something like the following :

```rust
use crossterm::event::poll as crossterm_poll;
use std::future::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::task::{Context, Poll};
use std::time::Duration;

use tokio::time::{sleep, timeout};

struct Polled {}

impl Polled {
    pub fn new() -> Polled {
        Polled {}
    }
}

impl Future for Polled {
    type Output = bool;

    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        // If there are events pending, it returns "Ok(true)", else it returns instantly
        let poll_status = crossterm_poll(Duration::from_secs(0));
        if poll_status.is_ok() && poll_status.unwrap() {
            return Poll::Ready(true);
        }
        Poll::Pending
    }
}

pub async fn poll(d: Duration) -> Result<bool, ()> {
    let polled = Polled::new();

    match timeout(d, polled).await {
        Ok(b) => Ok(b),
        Err(_) => Err(()),
    }
}
```

It *technically* works but obivously the program started using 100% CPU all the time since the executor always try to poll the future in case there's something new. Thus I wanted to add some asynchronous equivalent to sleep, that would delay the next time the executor tries to poll the Future, so I tried adding the following (right before returning `Poll::Pending`), which obviously did not work since `sleep_future::poll()` just returns `Pending` :

```rust
        let mut sleep_future = sleep(Duration::from_millis(50));
        tokio::pin!(sleep_future);
        sleep_future.poll(cx);
        cx.waker().wake_by_ref();
```

The fact that poll is not `async` forbids the use of `async` functions, and I'm starting to wonder if what I want to do is actually feasible, or if I'm not diving in my first problem the wrong way.

Is finding a way to do some `async` sleep the good way to go ?
If not, what is it ? Am I missing something in the asynchronous paradigm ?
Or is it just sometimes impossible to wrap some synchronous logic into a Future if the crate does not give you the necessary tools to do so ?

Thanks in advance anyway !

EDIT : I found a way to do what I want using an `async` block :

```rust
pub async fn poll(d: Duration) -> Result<bool, ()> {
    let mdr = async {
        loop {
            let a = crossterm_poll(Duration::from_secs(0));
            if a.is_ok() && a.unwrap() {
                break;
            }
            sleep(Duration::from_millis(50)).await;
        }
        true
    };

    match timeout(d, mdr).await {
        Ok(b) => Ok(b),
        Err(_) => Err(()),
    }
}
```

Is it the idiomatic way to do so ? Or did I miss something more elegant ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using an `async` block is a good way to *compose* futures, like your custom poller and tokio's `sleep`.

However, if you did want to write your own `Future` which also invokes tokio's `sleep`, here's what you would need to do differently:

1. Don't call `wake_by_ref()` immediately — the sleep future will take care of that when its time comes, and that's how you avoid spinning (using 100% CPU).
2. You must construct the `sleep()` future *once* when you intend to sleep (not every time you're polled), then *store it in your future* (this will require pin-projection) and poll the same future again the next time you're polled. That's how you ensure you wait the intended amount of time and not shorter.

Async blocks are usually a much easier way to get the same result.